# Print Sentences of Array, If They Contain the Given Word

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I hope it won't be difficult to figure out these symbols. I need to print all the sentences from `sentences[]` which have the same index as the sentences of `sentencesRemovedPuncts[]` having the word "մի՛" (in this case, in general any word) in them.

```js
var sentences = ["մի՛ գնար՝ ի տուն։", "մի անգամ, գեթ մի․․․։", "Զ՞ինչ մի՛թե է այս։"]
var sentencesRemovedPuncts = ["մի՛ գնար ի տուն", "մի անգամ գեթ մի", "Զինչ միթե է այս"] 
let word = "մի՛"
let key = new RegExp(`\b${word}\b`)
for (let i = 0; i < sentencesRemovedPuncts.length; i++) {
  if (key.test(sentencesRemovedPuncts[i])) {
    console.log(sentences[i])
  }
}
```

But my code doesn't output anything.

Comment: 1) `'\b'` is a BACKSPACE char, not a word boundary, `'\\b'` is. 2) `\b` is only a word boundary for ASCII letter words, they do not cover all Unicode.

Comment: These conditions would also do the job `sentencesRemovedPuncts[i].includes(word)` or `sentencesRemovedPuncts[i].indexOf(word) !== -1`. Creating regular expression from a string variable is not recommended.

Comment: @Wazeed But in this cases sentences that contain word with symbols of `word` will also be printed. Like it will think sentence includes word "corn" if it has the word "unicorn"

Comment: Then this condition would work in short `sentencesRemovedPuncts[i].split(" ").indexOf(word) !== -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below snippet to find if the word exists in a string

```js
// (String).split(" ").indexOf(word) !== -1
sentencesRemovedPuncts[i].split(" ").indexOf(word) !== -1
```

Below is the `RegExp` to find unicode sentences

```js
let word = "մի՛"
let bound = `[\\s\\r\\n]{1}`;
let key = new RegExp(`^(${word}${bound})|(${bound}${word}${bound})|(${bound}${word})$`)
...
key.test(sentencesRemovedPuncts[i])
```

Comment: RegExp doesn't work, but `(String).split(" ").indexOf(word) !== -1` works. I just didn't want to use split, but it seems there's no a better option.

Comment: @Davitpetrosyan, for the given example in question, both the split condition and regular expression has returned same result